# Django load static jquery script

Tags: jquery, django, include

I have two Django templates, one for the detail-update view and one for the create view. I use a simple jquery script to show/hide html fields depending on the selected component_type by the user. However this jquery script is identical for the create and detail-update templates (violates DRY-principle). So I would like to save it in a seperate file. How to do this?

The create template is saved at MyApp/templates/MyApp/create.html and is defined as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery_script.js' %}"></script>

{% block content %}
<h2>Create new component</h2>

{% include 'snippets/form-snippet.html' with form=form %}

{% endblock %}
```

I have the script saved at MyApp/static/MyApp/js/jquery_script.js and is defined as follows:

```
<script>
{% block jquery %}

    $(document).ready(function(){
        hideShow()
    })

    $('#id_component_type').click(function(){
        hideShow()
    });

    function hideShow(){
        if(document.getElementById('id_component_type').options[document.getElementById('id_component_type').selectedIndex].value == "k_v")
        {
            $('#id_length').parents('p:first').hide();
            $('#id_k_v').parents('p:first').show();
        }else
        {
            $('#id_length').parents('p:first').show();
            $('#id_k_v').parents('p:first').hide();
        }
    }

{% endblock %}
</script>
```

My settings file should be configured correctly (with debug=True at least). Some of the applicable settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest of the app',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put you script in the static folder and then include it as:

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'js/yourscript.js' %}"></script>
```

Further documentation about static files [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/).

Answer (score 0):

> Create a Jquery plugin with desired functionalities and link as internal style sheet into the template.html.
>
> Click [here](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) to learn to create Jquery Plugins
>
> Its simple to create. Please make use of it.